# Modify arguments after calling exec.Cmd() in Go

Tags: go, command

I am trying to run command with `exec.Cmd(command, flags...)` and want to have the flexibility to modify the arguments before calling the `cmd.Run()` function.

for example:

```
cmd := exec.Command("echo", "hello world")
cmd.Env = []string{"env1=1"}
cmd.Args = []string{"echo2", "oh wait I changed my mind"}
cmd.Run()
```

The above code seems to be always running `echo hello world` but not `echo2 oh wait I changed my mind`

Am I correct to expect `echo2` to be run instead of `echo`?

Comment: Note that when you call `exec.Command`, the first parameter is the command, subsequent parameters are the args. So your code changes the actual execution to (shell equivalent) `echo "echo2" "oh wait I changed my mind"`. To change the command to execute, not just its args, you have to update `cmd.Path`.

Comment: Ah thank you @Adrian. It seems so :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When changing the command to execute, you must also set [cmd.Path](https://godoc.org/os/exec#Cmd.Path) as in  [exec.Command](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a032f74bf0b40a94669159e7d7e96722eb76199b/src/os/exec/exec.go#L152-L162).

```
cmd := exec.Command("echo", "hello world")
cmd.Env = []string{"env1=1"}
cmd.Args = []string{"echo2", "oh wait I changed my mind"}

lp, err := exec.LookPath("echo2")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

cmd.Path = lp
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Cerise and @Tom